# MySQL capture user login info if user has Normal/SUPER user permission

Tags: mysql, linux, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

MySQL capture user login info like login time, user, host if user has Normal/SUPER user permission.

Tried to insert some user login info using below code

```
SET GLOBAL init_connect="CALL audit.login_trigger()";
```

audit.login_trigger() is SP. Ref: https://www.fromdual.com/mysql-logon-and-logoff-trigger-for-auditing

This SP will capture user info but we are not able to capture SUPER user login info if SUPER user connect to database server.

init_connect won't execute for SUPER user as per MySQL official document(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_init_connect).

Is anyone tried to overcome this scenario?

Comment: All logins are captured in the general query log (if enabled). This can be a database table if you don't have filesystem access.

Comment: Also there are [audit plugins](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/writing-audit-plugins.html) (which will also allow you to capture failed logins).